# MQTT Client - Default Message Handler

Tags: c++, mqtt

In MQTT client, I've added a callback function to default message Handler, to handle all the Topics by default. But when i try to publish a Topic from Client. default message handler is not receiving a callback. 
Is i'm missing anything???

Comment: Please create a minimum working example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without being able to see your code we have no way of knowing what you might have missed